# How to make group operation generic

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Suppose I have this grouping:

```
Iterable<WorkExperience> list =
            Arrays.asList
                    (
                       new WorkExperience(2001, "2001"),
                       new WorkExperience(2001, "2002"),
                       new WorkExperience(2001, "2003"),
                       new WorkExperience(2002, "2004")
                    );


    Stream<WorkExperience> stream = StreamSupport.stream(list.spliterator(), false);
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map = stream
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(WorkExperience::getYear,
                    Collectors.mapping(WorkExperience::getYearName, Collectors.toList())));
```

It builds a map which contains work experience objects grouped by year. Works fine. How to make this grouping operation generic?

Ideally I want to do next:

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new Grouping(list, WorkExperience::getYear, WorkExperience::getYearName).value();
    List<Object> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Object(), new Object());
    Map<Integer, List<String>> map2 = new Grouping(list2, (obj) -> obj.hashCode, (obj) -> obj.toString).value();
```

Comment: What you want to do, is to convert hardcoded expressions into parameters. It becomes quiet easy if you recall that [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) do already have that flexibility, therefore declare parameters suitable for that. Just look, how these parameters are declared and use similar parameters.

Comment: `groupingBy` is **already** generic.

Comment: Federico, thanks, I fixed a title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to use generics where you use concrete class now.

```
public static <T, K, V> Map<K, List<V>> groupBy(
    Iterable<T> list,
    Function<T, K> keyMapper,
    Function<T, V> valueMapper) {
  Stream<T> stream = StreamSupport.stream(list.spliterator(), false);
  return stream
      .collect(
          Collectors.groupingBy(keyMapper,
          Collectors.mapping(valueMapper, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Comment: *FULL ANSWER IS IN PROGRESS* - really? Why don't you post it complete at all.

Answer (score 0):

This it `GroupUtils` from one of my project. I use it to group collection by some key field, when only single element for each key, or multiple ones.

```
public class GroupUtils {
    public static <K, V> Map<K, List<V>> groupMultipleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> classifier) {
        return CollectionUtils.isEmpty(data) ? Collections.emptyMap() : data.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList())));
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> groupSingleBy(Collection<V> data, Function<V, K> keyMapper) {
        return groupSingleBy(data, keyMapper, Function.identity());
    }

    public static <K, V, S> Map<K, V> groupSingleBy(Collection<S> data, Function<S, K> keyMapper, Function<S, V> valueMapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(data).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper));
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of these three methods matches what the OP does. You might not realize that due to the obfuscated `Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, Collectors.mapping(Function.identity(), Collectors.toList()))` which does exactly the same as `Collectors.groupingBy(classifier)`…